# Replace placeholders of contentEditable with rendered components in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to replace placeholders like **#fa-face-smile#** to fontawesome emoticons in my editable div.

```
    <div
        contentEditable="true"
        ref={newMessageRef}
        className={`form-control ${errors.message ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
        data-raw=""
        onBlur={e => setNewEditableContent(e.target.textContent)}
    />
```

So I in my editable div I am writing and inserting emoticon as following:

> I would be so happy if #fa-face-smile# would be converted to the actual emoticon"

It should convert the placeholder with:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon size="2x" icon="fa-solid fa-face-smile" />
```

The function I use to update the innerHTML of the editable div is:

```
    function convertEmoticons(string) {
    
        let replacedText = string
            .split(new RegExp(/\#(.*?)\#/, "gi"))
            .map((node, i) => (i % 2 ? <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color: '#a70000'}} size="2x" icon={getEmoticon(node)}/> : node));
    
        return (replacedText);
    }
```

The new message is set like so:

```
const _setMessageText = (text) => {
    newMessageRef.current.setAttribute("data-raw", text);
    newMessageRef.current.textContent = convertEmoticons(text);
}
```

And the icon is inserted like so:

```
const insertEmoticon = (icon) => {

    let currentText = _getMessageText();
    let caretPos = getCaretPosition(newMessageRef.current);
    let iconPlaceholder = "#" + icon + "#";
    let newText = [currentText.slice(0, caretPos), iconPlaceholder, currentText.slice(caretPos)].join(' ');

    _setMessageText(newText);

}
```

However, all I get is **,[object, object],**. Note the commas at the beginning and end as well?!

[image]

How can I achieve that each replaced FontAwesomeIcon component is rendered before setting **newMessageRef.current.innerHTML** of the editable div?

Answer (score 0):

I've created 3 states,

- isEditing, to track if the user is editing
- editContent, for when the user edits the content
- displayContent, for converted content to display in the message

As you can see I've removed the `ref` but if you need it for something else you can obviously add it back.

We get the user input (text), get the icon labels, and split on the **#**. Then we map over the splitted text and check if the text item is a icon, if it is we return a `FontAwesomeIcon` component instead of the text.

```js
function App() {
  const [editContent, setEditContent] = useState(
    "I would be so happy if #fa-face-smile# would be converted to the actual emoticon"
  );
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [displayContent, setDisplayContent] = useState(null);

  function handleOnBlur(text) {
    // update the edit content
    setEditContent(text);
    // split the icon indicators
    const textAndIconLabels = text.split("#");
    // get the actual icons
    const icons = [...text.matchAll(/(?<=#)[a-z\-]+(?=#)/g)].flat();

    // loop over the textAndIconLabels
    const textAndIcons = textAndIconLabels.map((textOrIcon) => {
      // if the text is not a icon just return
      if (icons.includes(textOrIcon) === false) return textOrIcon;
      // if the text is a icon e.g. "fa-face-smile"
      return <FontAwesomeIcon icon={"fa-solid " + textOrIcon} />;
    });

    // update the displayContent
    setDisplayContent(textAndIcons);
    // set editing to false
    setIsEditing(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        contentEditable="true"
        className={`form-control ${errors.message ? "is-invalid" : ""}`}
        onClick={() => setIsEditing(true)} // or focus
        onBlur={(e) => handleOnBlur(e.target.textContent)}
      >
        {isEditing ? editContent : <>{displayContent}</>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See here a [live codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-currying-5u5667?file=/src/App.js)